# Asterisk at the end of required label

Tags: angular, css, sass, compass-sass

I am using angular with scss for one of my projects. I am in a situation where i have to display a asterisk with the label when the field is required.

Currently i have this code:

```css
h1{
  color: green;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  cursor: text;
  top: 24px;
  font-size: 113px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

label.required:not(:empty):after,
.field-header.required:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1><label class="required">something</label></h1>
```

This displays a asterisk properly in the required manner. But i want my asterisk to be displayed at all times irrespective of the width of the screen . Currently '*' wont be displayed in smaller screens ,only ellipsis is displayed.

> Current behavior
>
> data....
>
> Expected behaviour
>
> data... *

How to go about solving this ? Plunk link https://plnkr.co/edit/VCSa9iTLRBGYcDdnBzg1?p=preview Please help

Comment: Can you post your complete code? It seems like this should work.

Comment: Someone just -1'd my quetion. Can you please tell why so that i can fix it.!!

Comment: Hey Pete ..wel, its not about screen width , its about text overflow ..!! Once the text overflown, along with the ellipsis i want to show the asterisk at all conditions

Comment: Yeah sorry, just saw where your ellipsis is being applied, would you be averse to adding another span? https://jsfiddle.net/49qLhswu/, the problem is your after is part of the label (at the end and as you have overflow hidden, it is part of the hidden overflow!)

Comment: Hey thanks but i dont have control over html template part , should be done in the styling end as this happens dynamically.

Comment: Here you go https://plnkr.co/edit/VCSa9iTLRBGYcDdnBzg1?p=preview

Comment: Not much you can do then as the after will always be hidden by the overflow hidden as it will be the last thing in the label

Comment: i can use before instead of after and make it float right .. but its too much right , not able to align it to the label .Any way you could look into this ? https://plnkr.co/edit/40J24LygZHbbUzmJZoQX?p=preview

Comment: Yes, although you would be required to set the `label` element `width` property value to `auto` instead of `100%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **`position: absolute`** for **`*`** in **`:after`**. Use **`max-width: 100%`** instead of width.

I have made some changes in your css.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body h1 {
  color: green;
}

label {
  font-size: 113px;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: 0;
}

label.required:not(:empty):after,
.field-header.required:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <label class="required">Something beautiful</label>
</h1>
```

Comment: I think this has the same problem as mentioned in the last comments above - if the page is wider (or the text smaller), the * will be too the far right, and not directly after the label text.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah you were right. I updated my answer. The issue is fixed. `max-width` did the trick.

Comment: Still wondering whether absolute positioning the label is necessary in the first place (was in OP's example already, I'm aware) - otherwise `display: inline-block` and auto width should have done it, too, I think ...

Comment: @CBroe I tried, but only `display: inline-block` and `width: auto` not working, `max-width: 100%` is compulsory. As `position` concern I think it up to OP he wants to keep it or not

Comment: Might be I left the max-width in while playing around with it in dev tools - makes sense, too, because otherwise `white-space: nowrap` would of course make it extend beyond 100% ... Issue solved, I guess, just wondering if it wasn't unnecessarily complicated by throwing in absolute in the first place :-) (But OP might have other, unstated reasons for that of course.)